SQL Server running on Mac M1, MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON triggers transport-level error
I´m running MacOS 14.7.1, with SQL Server 2019 latest running in a container, and while on Windows 11 it works fine, on Mac it crashes with

Script log:


Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A
transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
server.


SQL server log:


2024-12-05 14:14:49.43 Logon Login failed for
user 'xx'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database
'Table1'. [CLIENT: 172.18.0.1]

Disabling MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON makes it work. I tried to update the SQL version, but I get the same issue.
Server side config looks good, I´m stuck on troubleshooting. Any ideas?

What driver/code do you use in C#, perhaps try to update that as well, not sure the errors you're writing are related though

I use powershell to run scripts, but when I try to run the same command I get: Cannot create memory optimized tables. To create memory optimized tables, the database must have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_FILEGROUP that is online and has at least one container.
But the FG is set correctly, I´ve triplechecked.

Update: using 2022-latest image actually solves the issue, but still, if somebody can advise what causes this and how to solve it for 2019-latest, I would be thankful, that is the production version, would prefer to keep the same.
